# Categorical variable as independent variable

Tags: regression, stata, binary-data, fixed-effects-model, variable

I am using the variable education level as a control variable and this variable consists of 7 education levels (1-7). Now I can't use it as it is converted in the data. My teacher has messaged me that I have to use education fixed effects by computing the variable into a binary variable for each education level, however, I am not sure how to do this in stata.

Does anyone have tips on how to covert this variable?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to that.
simply type

```
regress yvar xvar i.educvar
```

where y is your dependent variable,
x are all other independent variables, and
educvar is your education variable in categories.

If you have stata 12 or above, it will automatically create the binary variables in the background.